# Reading a few lines as Numpy array from a huge file

Tags: python-2.7, file, numpy

I have a text file that contains a billion words and their corresponding 300 dimensional word vectors.I need to extract a few thousands of words & their words vectors from the file & store them as Numpy arrays.Size of the text file is around 1 GB.
Naively, I tried to load the whole file in an array using genfromtxt but that did not worked.Then I tried to read the whole file line by line(each line in the file consists of a word and its word vector), looking for the word and extracting the word vector but I guess, that requires one pass over the file per word and as I need thousands of words, it will need to iterate over the whole file thousands of time.
What would be the fastest and most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Since `genfromtxt` accepts generators as input, you could make one to filter out all the lines you do not need, so `genfromtxt` would only see the words you want it to see.

Comment: It's not clear.  Are you just trying to read `N` lines, or all the lines that contain a specific set of words?  You can always read the file line by line, parse each, collect values, and quit when you want.  It won't be slower than `genfromtxt`.

Comment: @hpaulj I have a set of words, every word in that set appears only once in the file.In the file, no two words from the set appear in the same line and I am trying to read lines that corresponds to the words in my set.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know this is the fastest (probably not) but it works reasonably well (I tested it on a >100,000 lines file):

```
F = filter(lambda s: s.strip().split()[0] in word_set if s.strip() else False,
           open(fn, 'rt'))
x = np.genfromtxt(F, *yourargs, **yourkwds)
```

This is for Python2. In Python3 it seems one has to `.encode()` the input.