# Using numpy to extract data from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I'm working with `numpy` and trying to find which platform sold the most copies in NA region.

I have a CSV file holding a lot of data looking like this:

```
Rank,Name,Platform,Year,Genre,Publisher,NA_Sales,EU_Sales,JP_Sales,Other_Sales,Global_Sales
1,Wii Sports,Wii,2006,Sports,Nintendo,41.49,29.02,3.77,8.46,82.74
2,Super Mario Bros.,NES,1985,Platform,Nintendo,29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,40.24
3,Mario Kart Wii,Wii,2008,Racing,Nintendo,15.85,12.88,3.79,3.31,35.82
4,Wii Sports Resort,Wii,2009,Sports,Nintendo,15.75,11.01,3.28,2.96,33
5,Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue,GB,1996,Role-Playing,Nintendo,11.27,8.89,10.22,1,31.37
6,Tetris,GB,1989,Puzzle,Nintendo,23.2,2.26,4.22,0.58,30.26
7,New Super Mario Bros.,DS,2006,Platform,Nintendo,11.38,9.23,6.5,2.9,30.01
8,Wii Play,Wii,2006,Misc,Nintendo,14.03,9.2,2.93,2.85,29.02
9,New Super Mario Bros. Wii,Wii,2009,Platform,Nintendo,14.59,7.06,4.7,2.26,28.62
10,Duck Hunt,NES,1984,Shooter,Nintendo,26.93,0.63,0.28,0.47,28.31
11,Nintendogs,DS,2005,Simulation,Nintendo,9.07,11,1.93,2.75,24.76
```

I would like to print the platform with the most sales and the amount sold in the NA region. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I hard coded all the different platform as masks like:
maskNES = (data[:,2] == 'NES')

and then i assigned it to a variable like:
pfNES = data[maskNES][:,6].sum()

lastly i compared all the platforms to find the one with the highest value.
Just seems like a idiotic way of doing it. If i were to have thousands of different platforms
Oh and i took the csv data into a matrix called 'data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pandas this is fairly straight forward.

**Code:**

```
# read csv data into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(data, skipinitialspace=True)

# roll up by NA Sales
platform_roll_up = df.groupby('Platform')['NA_Sales'].sum()

# find row with max sales
idx_max = platform_roll_up.idxmax()

# show platform and sales for max
print(idx_max, platform_roll_up[idx_max])
```

**Results:**

```
Wii 101.71
```

**Test Data:**

```
data = StringIO(u"""
    Rank,Name,Platform,Year,Genre,Publisher,NA_Sales,EU_Sales,JP_Sales,Other_Sales,Global_Sales
    1,Wii Sports,Wii,2006,Sports,Nintendo,41.49,29.02,3.77,8.46,82.74
    2,Super Mario Bros.,NES,1985,Platform,Nintendo,29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,40.24
    3,Mario Kart Wii,Wii,2008,Racing,Nintendo,15.85,12.88,3.79,3.31,35.82
    4,Wii Sports Resort,Wii,2009,Sports,Nintendo,15.75,11.01,3.28,2.96,33
    5,Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue,GB,1996,Role-Playing,Nintendo,11.27,8.89,10.22,1,31.37
    6,Tetris,GB,1989,Puzzle,Nintendo,23.2,2.26,4.22,0.58,30.26
    7,New Super Mario Bros.,DS,2006,Platform,Nintendo,11.38,9.23,6.5,2.9,30.01
    8,Wii Play,Wii,2006,Misc,Nintendo,14.03,9.2,2.93,2.85,29.02
    9,New Super Mario Bros. Wii,Wii,2009,Platform,Nintendo,14.59,7.06,4.7,2.26,28.62
    10,Duck Hunt,NES,1984,Shooter,Nintendo,26.93,0.63,0.28,0.47,28.31
    11,Nintendogs,DS,2005,Simulation,Nintendo,9.07,11,1.93,2.75,24.76
""")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
I'm trying to work with a solution that works for numpy.ndarray. Which doesn't have a iloc attribute. Should i stay away from ndarray in this case? Also I'm trying to find total NA_Sales value of all product of X platform. Instead of finding the highest single value. By the way, I am new to python

Comment: Thanks a ton! Greatly appreciate the answer, your edited version was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Loading this with `genfromtxt` is straight forward:

```
In [280]: data=np.genfromtxt('stack42602390.csv',delimiter=',',names=True, dtype=None)

In [281]: data
Out[281]: 
array([ ( 1, b'Wii Sports', b'Wii', 2006, b'Sports', b'Nintendo',  41.49,  29.02,   3.77,  8.46,  82.74),
       ( 2, b'Super Mario Bros.', b'NES', 1985, b'Platform', b'Nintendo',  29.08,   3.58,   6.81,  0.77,  40.24),
       ( 3, b'Mario Kart Wii', b'Wii', 2008, b'Racing', b'Nintendo',  15.85,  12.88,   3.79,  3.31,  35.82),
....
       (11, b'Nintendogs', b'DS', 2005, b'Simulation', b'Nintendo',   9.07,  11.  ,   1.93,  2.75,  24.76)], 
      dtype=[('Rank', '<i4'), ('Name', 'S25'), ('Platform', 'S3'), ('Year', '<i4'), ('Genre', 'S12'), ('Publisher', 'S8'), ('NA_Sales', '<f8'), ('EU_Sales', '<f8'), ('JP_Sales', '<f8'), ('Other_Sales', '<f8'), ('Global_Sales', '<f8')])
```

The `b'string'` is just the Python3 way of showing bytestrings, the default string format from `genfromtxt`.  They won't show in Py2.

The result is a structured array, with different field names and types.  It is not a 2d array with rows and columns.

The `NA_Sales` data:

```
In [282]: data['NA_Sales']
Out[282]: 
array([ 41.49,  29.08,  15.85,  15.75,  11.27,  23.2 ,  11.38,  14.03,
        14.59,  26.93,   9.07])
```

And the maximum of these:

```
In [283]: np.argmax(data['NA_Sales'])
Out[283]: 0
```

and the corresponding record:

```
In [284]: data[0]
Out[284]: (1, b'Wii Sports', b'Wii', 2006, b'Sports', b'Nintendo',  41.49,  29.02,  3.77,  8.46,  82.74)
```

To make the most use of this array you'll have to read up on structured arrays.

Comment: Tried this solution but ran into the problem that longer down my csv file there is commas inside the titles and i couldn't add _quotechar=' " '_ to np.getfromtext

Comment: The `csv` package handles quotes, but the `numpy` readers don't.  `genfromtxt` accepts input from anything that feeds it lines, so you can preprocess the lines, cleaning them up so they can be parsed with simple delimiters.  That's been discussed in many previous SO questions.

Comment: A recent example of `genfromtxt` with a filter input: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42593389/901925